# Android: launch app crash

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

It through this message error when launching app
I'm using eclipse to run a mini game from project.android which is generated by Coco2d-x

```
 07-17 01:26:31.173: E/Trace(853): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    07-17 01:26:31.283: D/dalvikvm(853): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/xxx-1/libcocos2dcpp.so 0x40ce7d18
    07-17 01:26:31.403: D/dalvikvm(853): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/xxx-1/libcocos2dcpp.so 0x40ce7d18
    07-17 01:26:31.593: D/Cocos2dxActivity(853): model=sdk
    07-17 01:26:31.593: D/Cocos2dxActivity(853): product=sdk
    07-17 01:26:31.593: D/Cocos2dxActivity(853): isEmulator=true
    07-17 01:26:31.923: D/libEGL(853): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
    07-17 01:26:31.933: D/(853): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a157bb8, tid 868
    07-17 01:26:31.983: D/libEGL(853): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
    07-17 01:26:31.993: D/libEGL(853): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
    07-17 01:26:32.145: D/(853): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a15fad8, tid 853
    07-17 01:26:32.233: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853): <dict>
    07-17 01:26:32.233: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853):    cocos2d.x.version: cocos2d-x 2.2.4
    07-17 01:26:32.233: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853):    cocos2d.x.compiled_with_profiler: false
    07-17 01:26:32.233: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853):    cocos2d.x.compiled_with_gl_state_cache: true
    07-17 01:26:32.233: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853):    gl.vendor: Google (NVIDIA Corporation)
    07-17 01:26:32.233: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853):    gl.renderer: Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (GeForce 210/PCIe/SSE2)
    07-17 01:26:32.233: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853):    gl.version: OpenGL ES 2.0 (3.3.0)
    07-17 01:26:32.233: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853):    gl.max_texture_size: 8192
    07-17 01:26:32.233: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853):    gl.max_texture_units: 16
    07-17 01:26:32.233: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853):    gl.supports_PVRTC: false
    07-17 01:26:32.233: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853):    gl.supports_NPOT: true
    07-17 01:26:32.233: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853):    gl.supports_BGRA8888: false
    07-17 01:26:32.233: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853):    gl.supports_discard_framebuffer: false
    07-17 01:26:32.233: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853):    gl.supports_vertex_array_object: false
    07-17 01:26:32.233: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853): </dict>
    07-17 01:26:32.753: D/cocos2d-x debug info(853): Get data from file(config.txt) failed!
    07-17 01:26:32.753: W/dalvikvm(853): JNI WARNING: illegal class name 'xxx/MLExternal' (FindClass)
    07-17 01:26:32.753: W/dalvikvm(853):              (should be formed like 'dalvik/system/DexFile')
    07-17 01:26:32.753: W/dalvikvm(853):              or '[Ldalvik/system/DexFile;' or '[[B')
    07-17 01:26:32.753: I/dalvikvm(853): "GLThread 75" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
    07-17 01:26:32.753: I/dalvikvm(853):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40cf4178 self=0x2a180240
    07-17 01:26:32.764: I/dalvikvm(853):   | sysTid=868 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=706080464
    07-17 01:26:32.775: I/dalvikvm(853):   | state=R schedstat=( 253527116 637016288 63 ) utm=11 stm=14 core=0
    07-17 01:26:32.803: I/dalvikvm(853):   #00  pc 000012a0  /system/lib/libcorkscrew.so (unwind_backtrace_thread+27)
    07-17 01:26:32.803: I/dalvikvm(853):   #01  pc 0005faa8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget const*, int)+35)
    07-17 01:26:32.803: I/dalvikvm(853):   #02  pc 00053914  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*, Thread*, bool)+303)
    07-17 01:26:32.813: I/dalvikvm(853):   #03  pc 000539ae  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+25)
    07-17 01:26:32.813: I/dalvikvm(853):   #04  pc 00038aba  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    07-17 01:26:32.813: I/dalvikvm(853):   #05  pc 000417c2  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    07-17 01:26:32.813: I/dalvikvm(853):   #06  pc 00163ddc  /data/app-lib/xxx-1/libcocos2dcpp.so
    07-17 01:26:32.823: I/dalvikvm(853):   #07  pc 00163eb6  /data/app-lib/xxx-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (makeWebViewsJNI+17)
    07-17 01:26:32.823: I/dalvikvm(853):   #08  pc 00163c5a  /data/app-lib/xxx-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (MLExternal::ExternalProc::makeWebViews(char const*, char const*)+1)
    07-17 01:26:32.823: I/dalvikvm(853):   #09  pc 0016af6c  /data/app-lib/xxx-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (GameManager::GameManager()+251)
    07-17 01:26:32.823: I/dalvikvm(853):   #10  pc 0016b03e  /data/app-lib/xxx-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (GameManager::body()+21)
    07-17 01:26:32.833: I/dalvikvm(853):   #11  pc 001619be  /data/app-lib/xxx-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()+45)
    07-17 01:26:32.833: I/dalvikvm(853):   #12  pc 001f79d8  /data/app-lib/xxx-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::CCApplication::run()+3)
    07-17 01:26:32.833: I/dalvikvm(853):   #13  pc 001618d4  /data/app-lib/xxx-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeInit+63)
    07-17 01:26:32.833: I/dalvikvm(853):   #14  pc 0001e290  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
    07-17 01:26:32.833: I/dalvikvm(853):   #15  pc 0004d1f8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+391)
    07-17 01:26:32.833: I/dalvikvm(853):   #16  pc 00038b44  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCheckCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+7)
    07-17 01:26:32.833: I/dalvikvm(853):   #17  pc 0004f354  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmResolveNativeMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+171)
    07-17 01:26:32.833: I/dalvikvm(853):   #18  pc 000276a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    07-17 01:26:32.833: I/dalvikvm(853):   #19  pc 0002b540  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
    07-17 01:26:32.833: I/dalvikvm(853):   #20  pc 0005f9d4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+271)
    07-17 01:26:32.833: I/dalvikvm(853):   #21  pc 0005f9fe  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+19)
    07-17 01:26:32.843: I/dalvikvm(853):   #22  pc 00054576  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    07-17 01:26:32.843: I/dalvikvm(853):   #23  pc 0000e3b8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
    07-17 01:26:32.843: I/dalvikvm(853):   #24  pc 0000dab0  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
    07-17 01:26:32.843: I/dalvikvm(853):   at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeInit(Native Method)
    07-17 01:26:32.843: I/dalvikvm(853):   at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(Cocos2dxRenderer.java:72)
    07-17 01:26:32.843: I/dalvikvm(853):   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1494)
    07-17 01:26:32.843: I/dalvikvm(853):   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
    07-17 01:26:32.843: E/dalvikvm(853): VM aborting
    07-17 01:26:32.853: A/libc(853): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 868 (Thread-75)
```

Please help me, i try to search on google but there is  no helpful result
I tried to run on device, the app is not responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d

Notice the address is human readable.  That's on purpose-  its done so you know what happened.  In this case, you accessed Java memory that used to be valid but no longer is.  If you're saving objects between calls in the C code, you must increment the global reference count.  If you're not saving objects, its likely to be a race condition around memory passed to the C layer

Comment: Thank for your help. I can not find where is the reason :(

Comment: Are you keeping java object references in C++?  This includes memory for arrays-  make sure you aren't keeping them around and accessing them after you return to Java (unless you make a copy).  Same thing with strings.

Comment: There is not accessing object of C++ from Java :(

Comment: I found the reason, cause of using <fstream> to read file, thank Gabe Sechan :D